# Lenovo docking station issues - Going to sleep and not waking up with screens

Tags: multiple-monitors

Here is the setup:

L460
Thinkpad dock
2x Samsung monitors over Display Port
Ubuntu 16.04

---

Expected behavior:
I would expect that when the laptop is docked, and the lid is closed. The laptop internal display would be disconnected and not show up in Display Manager.

And when undocking the internal display should turn on as the primary display.

And re-docking the 2 external displays come back, and the internal one is disabled.

---

Actual behavior:
When the laptop is docked, and the lid is closed. Display manager detects all 3 screens and turns all 3 of them on. Setting one external display as the primary and then turning off the internal display works.

When undocking the laptop goes immediately to sleep. This can be fixed by setting the close lid action to do nothing in the power settings.

However, if the laptop does go to sleep, and it is connected to the dock with the lid closed, and then powered back on... The external screens never come back on. Only a restart brings them back.

---

This is probably not a bug. I guess it's just never been coded... after resuming from sleep i would expect the dock to be working and the external screens come back.

It would be nice if the dock worked as it should. Docking disables the internal display, undocking does NOT sleep the computer and the primary display is moved to the internal display. And re-docking disables the internal display and turns on the external displays.

Has anyone been able to get a Lenovo dock working correctly? I assume Ubuntu has the same problem with Dell and HP docks.

Comment: I am experiencing exctly the same problem, please anybody, help!

Comment: Same issue from an X1 Carbon running 14.04.